# Is this acceptable notation? (Partial Derivatives)

Tags: notation, divergence-operator

I have a question about the notation which I have decided to use. I'm writing lecture notes for my own Calculus course and I've introduced notation such as $[R_x-Q_y]_x$ and so on. It's supposed to mean the following

> Find the first partial derivative of the argument in the brackets w.r.t the variable that appears after the brackets

Here is the text that I've written (below)

As always, let us define $\vec{F}(x,y,z)$ as $$\vec{F}(x,y,z)=P(x,y,z)\, \vec{i}+Q(x,y,z)\, \vec{j}+R(x,y,z)\, \vec{k}$$ Computing the curl, we get \begin{align*} \nabla \times \vec{F}&=\begin{vmatrix} \vec{i}& \vec{j}& \vec{k} \\ \partial_x & \partial_y & \partial_z \\ P&Q&R \end{vmatrix}\\ &=(R_y-Q_z)\vec{i}-(R_x-P_z)\vec{j}+(Q_x-P_y)\vec{k}\end{align*} Computing the divergence, \begin{align*} \nabla\cdot(\nabla\times\vec{F})&=[R_y-Q_z]_x- [R_x-P_z]_y+[Q_x-P_y]_z\\
  &=R_{yx}-Q_{zx}-R_{xy}+P_{zy}+Q_{xz}-P_{yz} \\
  &=(R_{yz}-R_{yx})+(Q_{xz}-Q_{xz})+(P_{zy}-P_{zy}) \qquad \text{(by Clairaut's theorem)} \\ &=0 \end{align*}
    (QED)

Is this a good notation to use? Thanks

Comment: No objection, parenthesis can do as well.

Answer (score 1):

$$(P_x-Q_x)_y\equiv\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}(P_x-Q_x)$$ seems a natural convention.

Comment: Should I add that at the start of the document just to make sure everybody knows what it means?

Comment: @S.Feinberg: why not, though it is not difficult to figure out.

Comment: Always good to avoid confusion at all costs I guess.

Comment: I originally used the curly fraction way of writing it, but it's a lot easier and quicker writing the bracket form of partial derivatives

Comment: @S.Feinberg: I used parenthesis because brackets at the innermost nesting level may let think of a special meaning. Though IMO, the meaning is "standard", $(P_x-Q_x)$ is a function.

Comment: I agree with you there - I can always change them back to normal brackets if it causes confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the use of subscripts to denote derivatives is pretty common, so you're breaking no new ground here. I see two possible problems.

1. It might be tempting (to students!) to keep the subscripts in alphabetical order for "neatness", i.e., write $R_{xy}$ instead of $R_{yx}$. If you start out by saying "we're going to assume a level of continuity that lets us know that mixed partials are all equal," then this is OK ... indeed, it's probably good! But if you're not doing that, then you should probably make a note that order matters, and that $[R_x]_y$ becomes $R_{xy}$, i.e., that the order in which partials are computed is the left-to-right-order within the subscript.
2. I personally both *use* and  ***hate*** notations that depend on names. Suppose that we have two functions $(x, y) \mapsto f(x, y)$ and $(x, y) \mapsto g(x, y)$. Further suppose that $f(x, y) = g(y, x)$, and that both are differentiable. How is the derivative of $f$ with respect to its first argument related to the derivatives of $g$? Well, it looks as if 
   $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =
   \frac{\partial g}{\partial y},
   $$
   ...sort of. Perhaps if we add arguments, it'll be clearer:
   $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y) =
   \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(y, x).
   $$
   So ... when we compute that second thing, since $y$ is the first argument, did we differentiate with respect to the first argument or the second? You and I both know what's meant here (probably), but a beginning student is left just baffled. Far better, perhaps, is to say something like
   $$
   (\partial_1 f)(x, y) = (\partial_2 g)(x, y)
   $$
   where the "1" and "2" name the positions of the arguments with respect to which we are differentiating. Of course, this loses us lots of the mnemonic beauty of the chain rule, but it provides a gain in clarity as a trade-off.

Given problem 2, I'd advise using this notation for the course of this one proof, and perhaps a couple of other div/grad/etc proofs, and then abandoning it.